# View mismatched entries in a joined table

Tags: sql, select, join, inner-join

I have tables A, B, and C. B and C are in the same database but a different one from A.

I have a num column and an aid column in A. I have a rn column and a bcid column in B. The bcid column refers to the cid column in C. C also has an asid column.

I want a query such that I get all entries in A where the num and the rn entries match but the aid and asid entries differ.

So far, the best I can do is join tables B and C as such:

```
SELECT * FROM (B INNER JOIN C ON B.rob = C.cid)
```

I can't seem to alias the above table in my query however. I'd like to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM A, (SELECT * FROM (B INNER JOIN C ON B.rob = C.cid)) TMP
WHERE (A.num = TMP.rn AND A.aid <> TMP.asid)
```

But I run into errors. Any guidance in the right direction with this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:

I'll represent a Table as follows (assuming a table has n columns and m rows:

```
Name: (col1, col2,..., coln) [(entry1, entry2,... entry n), (entry n+1, entry n+2, ... entry 2n), ..., (entry (m-1)*n, entry (m-1)*n + 1, ..., entry (m*n))]
```

Sample Input:

```
A : (num, aid) [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,7)]
B : (rn, bcid) [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]
C : (cid, asid) [(1,3), (2,4), (3,2), (4,6)]
```

Correct Output:
    [(1,7)]

Output I've gotten:
[(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,7)]

I know why I've gotten the output though: I am assuming that the correspondence between A and the join of B and C are 1-to-1 but they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select *
from A
where not exists (
select 1 from B
inner join C on B.rob = C.cid
where A.aid = C.asid
and A.num = B.rn)
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I end up with more rows in this query than in the joining of B and C

Comment: @Steve So what do you want?  All the rows in A or all the rows in B/C that match?  Either can be done with a subselect.

Comment: I want all the rows in A where column num in A matches column rn in B, and column aid in A doesn't match column asid in C. However, I need to align the cid in C up with the corresponding rob column in B.

Comment: @Steve Let me know if option two with subselect works.

Comment: @Steve Can you give me some more information?  Maybe edit your question to show some example wrong output you are getting currently and include an example of what you want?

Comment: I included an example. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @Steve I just made an edit that reverses the logic.  I hope it will work.  Let me know what it does and the results it produces if they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
select *
from A 
inner join B on A.num = B.rn 
left join C on A.aid = C.asid and B.bcid = C.cid -- or B.rob? 
where C.asid is null
```

The left join, or left outer join, leaves you with all rows from A+B, filling in null where C doesn't match up with A and B per the 'on' condition.  Checking for null here should give you the answer you're looking for.